# Azure Databricks SQL query to join 3 tables is stuck at 93 million rows

Tags: sql, mysql, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to use **Join** to combine 3 tables on Azure Databricks SQL.

The code starts executing, and will be at 93 million rows. It stays at this stage and nothing more happens.

Below is the code:

```
Select 
    r.med, m.mbs, 
    r.sname, 
    r.apl, 
    m.han, 
    p.pt 
from 
    ‘hive_metastore.pdw’ p
join 
    ‘hive_metastore.rdm’ r    on p.pt = r.med 
join 
    ‘hive.metastore.mdw’ m  on r.med = m.han 
Order 
    By m.han 
desc
```

[image]

Comment: What are you planning to do with 90+ million rows?

Comment: You asked same question yesterday: [databricks SQL query to join 3 tables stuck at 93 million rows read (1GB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77179345/databricks-sql-query-to-join-3-tables-stuck-at-93-million-rows-read-1gb)

Answer (score 0):

I have 3 tables with 170M records in each table.
Even i got stuck at 510M records read.
This is because doing join to such table creates new record of 170M * 170M * 170M which is where huge data to handle and time consuming.

[image]

and

[image]

In your case it is 90M and i believe each table have at least 30M records.

So the possible solution is

1. Do filter on table whichever rows you don't required.
2. Making partition on column you frequently work.

Most of the time saves when you do filter on unwanted records.

I tried to limit 2 of the tables to 20 rows and done join on table with 170M rows.
The output result is  663M rows and took 2min 21s

[image]

Now you can imagine how it would be for you having
table around 30M records.
If you see i did not used order by, again it checks this huge records for sorting.

Below is the code of partitioning.

```
-- Create the partitioned table for pdw
CREATE  TABLE pdw_partitioned
PARTITIONED  BY (pt)
AS  SELECT  *  FROM pdw;

-- Create the partitioned table for rdm
CREATE  TABLE rdm_partitioned
PARTITIONED  BY (med)
AS  SELECT  *  FROM rdm;

  

-- Create the partitioned table for mdw
CREATE  TABLE mdw_partitioned
PARTITIONED  BY (han)
AS  SELECT  *  FROM mdw;
```

Then alter the query with filter on this partitioned tables.
Example:

```
Select
r.med, m.mbs,
r.sname,
r.apl,
m.han,
p.pt
from
(select pt from pdw limit  30000000) p
join
(select med,sname,apl FROM rdm where apl<1  and med in (2,3) limit  30000000) r on p.pt = r.med
join
(select han,mbs from mdw limit  20) m on r.med = m.han
```

Above query took 29 min with 3 worker nodes.

[image]

So try altering your query.